# Any method to retrieve the available serial numbers for an item?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the available (i.e. in stock) serial numbers from Items in QuickBooks Enterprise using qbxml. I've looked through OSR and the various Item Query requests as well as read the docs for the C-Data QuickBooks drivers. I'm not seeing a way to pull the available serial numbers out.

Anyone know if this is possible? Maybe there is a report that contains it?

Answer (score 0):

The OSR shows that you should be able to fetch them on InventoryTransactionQuery, but I'm currently running it against the sample "advanced inventory company" and it's returning "null" for the RetList.

Just parsed out the XML by toXmlString-ing the QBXML response:

Was doing it wrong:  It is the ret-list, you have to subparse it for things.

Only problem is that this does not include the bins, so your visibility of inventory is only to the warehouse level.

I'm finding information extremely sparse so I hope this is useful for someone, even if it's a necro for the OP.